# How can we get actual Video Url of LinkedIn Post and comments from LinkedIn API v2

Tags: linkedin-api, microsoft-documentation

While fetching post on LinkedIn profile, we are getting Digital Media Asset URN for Video and documents. What is a way to find actual URL of Video in API. We are using https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors.
I tried to add projection with request, but it is not returning expected Url.

Projection:
(paging,elements(*(author,created,distribution,firstPublishedAt,id,lastModified,lifecycleState,origin,specificContent(com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent(*,media(*(description,media(*(media(video~:playableStreams),thumbnails)),originalUrl,thumbnails)))),visibility)))

Comment: Did you find this out? I am stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The projection works if you don't use the bulk /ugcPosts?q=authors API and instead query the ugcPosts one at a time.

The following CURL command will get the video URL for a UGC Post.

```
curl -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" -H "Authorization: Bearer apikey" "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A6595780832772792320?viewContext=AUTHOR&projection=(specificContent(com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent(media(*(media~:playableStreams)))))"
```